# Meteor run ios - not working at all

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, ios-simulator

I have only created new project and added ios-platform.
This is what I get when I'm trying to run it on iOS-simulator:

```
$ meteor run ios
[[[[[ ~/Dropbox/Projects/testapp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
ios: failed to start the app.
ENOENT, open
'/Users/lehtu/Dropbox/Projects/testapp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log'
=> Started app on iOS Simulator.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

Also there is no platforms folder in that path it's telling me should be a console.log

Any ideas why this failed and what ENOENT means? Or better.. how to make this work?

Running in device doesn't work either:

```
$ meteor run ios-device
WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device.For the mobile app to be able to connect to
         the local server, make sure your device is on the same network, and that the network
         configuration allows clients to talk to each other (no client isolation).
[[[[[ ~/Dropbox/Projects/testapp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.

Could not open your project in Xcode.
Try running again with the --verbose option.
Instructions for running your app on an iOS device:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-run-your-app-on-an-iOS-device
```

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed & have you followed the instructions at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-run-your-app-on-an-iOS-device ? It looks like you don't have Xcode on your computer from the error above

Comment: Yes, I have Xcode installed and yes I followed that instruction.

Comment: do you have a line like require("console.log") or something like that in your project?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your cordova project and trying again? `rm -rf .meteor/local/cordova-build && meteor run ios`

Answer (score 1):

In the first case it looks like you would be trying to use `console.log` when the [Console plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console) isn't available for platform iOS, so you would need to first run

```
cordova platform add ios
```

to install the iOS as platform. This command will also generate the folder *platforms/ios/*. And after that, run the installation for plugin with

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
```

On the second case (*ios-device*) it seems clear that you are missing Xcode as *Akshat* already suggested on his comment. Thus you would need to install it as described in [link](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-run-your-app-on-an-iOS-device) provided by him.

Comment: If I create project with cordova it works just nicely on device and simulator. Once again I have Xcode installed and also those commandline tools.

I tried to add ios platform like you described but it is already in project and adding that plugin didn't nothing either :(